# Index Sources & Publish Symbols step fails in TFS 2015

Tags: indexing, tfs, build, symbols, tfs-2015

By default TFS Build creates a "Index Sources & Publish Symbols" step in a Visual Studio Build definition. When the step's property "Path to publish symbols" is empty, everything works fine. But when setting the path to a local directory, the step generates the following error:

```
2015-09-25T11:00:09.7991491Z Executing the powershell script: C:\NewAgent\tasks\PublishSymbols\1.0.4\PublishSymbols.ps1
2015-09-25T11:00:10.0022755Z Find-Files -SearchPattern **\bin\**\*.pdb -RootFolder C:\NewAgent\_work\990dcb3f\Projects
2015-09-25T11:00:10.0491548Z Found 15 files to index...
2015-09-25T11:00:10.0491548Z Invoke-IndexSources -RepositoryEndpoint <repositoryEndpoint> -SourceFolder C:\NewAgent\_work\990dcb3f\Projects -PdbFiles <pdbFiles>
2015-09-25T11:00:10.6272794Z Invoke-PublishSymbols -PdbFiles <pdbFiles> -Share C:\DebugSymbols -Product EntityMapper -Version 20150925.14 -MaximumWaitTime 7200000 -MaximumSemaphoreAge 1440 -ArtifactName 
2015-09-25T11:00:10.7348541Z ##[error]Can't infer artifact type from artifact location C:\DebugSymbols.
2015-09-25T11:00:10.7504779Z  
2015-09-25T11:00:10.7504779Z Start: AssociateArtifact
2015-09-25T11:00:10.7504779Z ##[error]Artifact Type is required.
2015-09-25T11:00:10.7504779Z End: AssociateArtifact
```

The pdb files are published to the specified directory, so i don't really understand what is causing the error (which then causes the whole build job to fail).

Answer (score 0):

> When the step's property "Path to publish symbols" is empty, everything works fine.

Yes, because if symbols path is not set, the script only index sources, not publishing symbols.

> But when setting the path to a local directory, the step generates the error

You need [prepare your symbol store](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh190722.aspx). In your case setup folder sharing and permissions.

Comment: Even with permissions set to Full control for Everyone on a local folder, the publish symbol step results in the error stated above.

Answer (score 0):

In my case changing the "Path to publish symbols" from

> //myserver/symbols

to

> \\myserver\symbols

solved the issue. Don't know why this happend to me but ok... :)